# parallel.for loop giving timeout exception

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Parallel.For to make concurrent calls as following.

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);                          
 connection.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
 //SqlDataReader reader;                            
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd.Connection = connection;
 Parallel.For(0, 100, delegate(int i)
 {
  //insert into database;
  cmd.CommandText = string.Format("insert into Service_LoadTest(id,ServiceCallcount) values ({0},'Call_{1}')", i, i);                               
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  });
```

After inserting some counts upto 70 ,i am getting timeout exception as "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.".I have set the connetion string timeout property,but of no luck. Please help.

Comment: SqlCommand is not thread safe, you can't do that.

Comment: Are you hoping that using `Parallel.For` will speed up your database inserts?

Comment: On the other end is single write head.   Unless you have some exotic sever on the other end this is not going to be faster.   The solution of opening a connection for each insert is not going to be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't thread-safe. Try moving all code into the loop:

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, delegate(int i)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {                          
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("insert into Service_LoadTest(id,ServiceCallcount) values ({0},'Call_{1}')", i, i);                               
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are opening connections without closing them, you are going to run in to problems. The SqlConnection objects need to be put in to a `using` block so they get properly disposed and closed.

Comment: I get this answers the question as stated but opening multiple connection for parallel input is not going to be faster than inserting serial on a single connection.  That Open is more expensive than the insert.   And for sure it is not scalable.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects each time and and intialising those to call ExecuteNonQuery separately for each query you should concatenate all queries and call ExecuteNonQuery only once for that concatenated query.

For implementing above just append all queries in CommandText seperated by ';' and then call ExecuteNonQuery.